# Changing The Color of Active Navigation Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a simple bootstrap top fixed navigation bar and I would like to change the color of the active page... however I think something is missing in my code

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav" id="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#skdill" >skisll</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#skill">skill</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#research">research</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                     </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS is

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar .nav {
   float: none;
}
.navbar .nav>li {
    width: 25%;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

#nav-collapse li a:hover { 
    color: blue; 
}
#nav-collapse a:hover { 

    background-color: gray; 
}

#nav-collapse  li.active { 
   color:green;
    background-color: yellow; 
}
#nav-collapse  li.active a {
    color: red;
}
```

... I would like for example the text (of the active navigation item) to be red and the background color to be gray (whatever)... do you have an idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: First off, there's no `.site_nav` element. Perhaps you meant `.nav`?

Comment: thank you indeed. I meant #nav-collapse instead

Comment: It should work... Check for other CSS conflicts that may override your code.

Comment: Why you put all links as active (`.active`) ?

Comment: I think I should explain better what I would like to have : when an user hovers over the sections skills for example, then the item skills become gray. If the user clicks on skills however, the item does not remain gray... which is what I would like to obtain! this is what I call an active item. Sorry if it is not the right terminology (I am a noobie)... what do you think? Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the state of the active item then you need to include the navbar layout in every html file. For example if you click on `Research` then in the `research.html` your navbar must be

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
      <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav" id="nav">
        <li ><a href="#skdill" >skisll</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#skill">skill</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#research">research</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And so on for all your links.

**EDIT**
You can use JavaScript and do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </style>
  </head>

  <script>
     $(function() {
        $('#nav li a').click(function() {
           $('#nav li').removeClass();
           $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
        });
     });
  </script>

  <body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
              <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
                 <ul class="nav" id="nav">
                     <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                     <li id="skill"><a href="#skill">Skill</a></li>
                     <li id="research"><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
                     <li id="link"><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ag47D/3/

Comment: thank you very much enrmarc but as I said above I only have a single html file. and the navigation bar allows the user to go back and forth through the different sections (research, etc). I simply would like the item research to remain gray when a user clicks on it, and then if the user clicks on another item (skill) then skill becomes gray etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar #nav > .active > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag47D/)**

Comment: Ohhhh probably I should mention that ALL THE NAVIGATION LINKS are on the SAME PAGE! This is probably why it does not work properly? Think of the page as a single resume/cv page with everything on it

Comment: @noobie_on_android Yup you should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer which is a bit different from other answers and worked very well for me:

Suppose the links in the navbar (on the local server, https://myweburl.com will be replaced by https://localhost:8000 or https://127.0.0.1:8000) are as follows:

Home => https://myweburl.com

Blog => https://myweburl.com/blog/1, https://myweburl.com/blog/2, etc.

Skills => https://myweburl.com/skills/

Contact => https://myweburl.com/contact/

So you can use this snippet to make the respective link in the navbar active:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href; // grabbing the url
    var str = loc.split("/")[3]; // splitting the url and taking the third string
    if(str.localeCompare("") == 0)
      $("#home").addClass("active");
    else
      $("#" + str).addClass("active");
});
```

Also, in your HTML, remove 'active' class and put respective IDs in all the links. By respective IDs, I mean that the ID should be named according to the URL.

What the above JS code is doing: Grabs the URL and splits it into an array of strings. Then it takes the 4th string in variable str (the fourth string will be at the third index). And then, it puts the 'active' class in that link.

The benefit of this method: Apart from the fact that it is very simple, if the user directly goes to the link instead of clicking the link in the navbar then also this method works.

Problem with this method: The URL of every link in the navbar must be known. If the format of the URL is different then a little change in the code can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This js worked for me, I placed it on each page where navigation is a php include:

```
 <script>
 $(function() { 

        var path = window.location.pathname;
        path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);

        $(".nav li a").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if(path.substring((path.lastIndexOf('/')+1),path.lenght) === href) {    
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass();
            }
        });         
 });
```

Comment: I  used console.log() to work out which substring to use. I tried to use onclick function, as I didn't want the active on first load, but it onclick function didn't work for me! <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="">
       <a href="index">Home</a> 
   </li>    
   <li class="">
   <a href="accomodation">Hotel</a> 
   </li></ul>