# bootstrap navbar active link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar and I want that the links get active pending which subdomain I am with Javascript. I researched all round the forum and I didn't found anything that worked. Help me please.

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbar-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a href='#'></a></li>
        <li><a href='#></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I will lead the answer by saying that doing anything with your nav that will leave your nav unusable if the visitor has JS disabled is a bad idea.

That said, please clarify - do you have multiple subdomains that are linked on your nav and you want to be able to highlight the one you are on, or do multiple links have different pages associate with it and you want to highlight the ones that apply to the subdomain?

Or, are you just looking to highlight the current page in the nav and by"subdomain" you meant subdirectory?

Comment: It's a repeated question. Check the link below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866136/changing-the-color-of-active-navigation-bar

Comment: I know that I repeated a question but it was because the answers  didn't worked me.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery because I'm lazy:

```
// Get the page URL
var url = window.location.href.split('/')

// Get the subdomain
var location = url[url.length-1]

// Apply active class to the link that matches the subdomain.
$('a[href$="' + location + '"]').addClass('active')
```

You'll need to modify this to your own use case.

Comment: `Bootstrap` has jQuery included (and requires it), so using it is valid in this case (even with the lack of the jQuery tag on the question)

Comment: Only the javascript components of Bootstrap require jQuery, but yea you're right, should be fine.

Comment: Need a lot more information than that. I.e. how is your URL formatted & what are the actual links.

Comment: Using the variable name "location" is causing an endless loop.  I've used this code and changed "location" to "loc", and the loop no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, but with jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $path = window.location.href;
  jQuery('a[href="' + $path + '"]').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}
a.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#">A Link</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Another link</a>
<a href="http://stacksnippets.net/js">Active link</a>
```

Comment: This maybe fits to me but I need that the jquery code is:
If path = "wanted link" then addClass('active) to element with its ID

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Solution with bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $("#link-football").addClass("active");
});
```