# how to change color of navbar active?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item mx-4">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
```

i want to change color active nav link in bootstrap
here my code but i get nothing, i need correction about this

```
 .navbar-nav > .active > a { 
    color: #28A745; 
   }
```

Comment: if you are using JS to change classes you don't need to select any element, just declare the .active class and that's it.

Comment: i dont using JS

Comment: check the answer for this question then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866136/changing-the-color-of-active-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector is not correct, you want to style the link ("a" element) with the css class "active" inside the ".navbar-nav" element, so a correct way to do it can be something like this :

```
.navbar-nav a.active { 
    color: #28A745; 
}
```

Comment: its not working